# Springboot responseBody return HTML

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following controller to return a html page.
The usage of ResponseBody is needed because of some reason.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(
        value = {"/dashboard/view/embed.htm"},
        method = {RequestMethod.GET},
        produces = {"text/html;charset=utf-8"}
    )
    public String execute(@RequestParam(required = false,name = "id") String embedId, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> context = this.buildPageContext(embedId, request);
        String templatePath = this.viewPath;
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(this.viewPath)) {
            templatePath = "template/fbi_embed.vm";
        }

        Template template = this.engine.getTemplate(templatePath, "UTF-8");
        VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext(context);
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        template.merge(velocityContext, stringWriter);
        return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
    }
```

The result I got in explore showing in the follow:

[image]

I don't know why the < and > become < and >
I use the spring-boot-starter-web 1.5.22.RELEASE

Comment: You might possibly need a MVC or MVVM design pattern, where V is your view (or HTML page to be precise) , you are returning string so possibly your HTML content is being parsed from < to &lt; and > to &gt;  !

Comment: What is expected output? How have you tried to achieve it?